# Getting null pointer exception when compariing object with null

Tags: java

```
public void log(Node no) {
  do {
        if (no != null) {
            System.out.println(no.getInfo() + " ");
        }
    
        no = no.prox;
    } while(no != null);
    
    if (no.prox != null) {
        // log(no.prim);
    }
}
```

On my main method i have a N-ary tree where i pass the tree to this method.

So, i got a nullPointerException in the **if**, why? Can someone explain me?

Comment: Loop exits when `no == null`, so `no.prox` causes an exception.

Comment: Also inside the loop, if `no` is `null`, you skip the `if` body but you deference anyway `no = no.prox` <-- will fail if `no` is `null`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a `do-while` loop, so `do` first happens before any condition is checked. Meanwhile, a normal `while` loop checks condition before executing the code. With that in mind:

1. Inside `do{}`, if `no == null`, the `if` statement is skipped and `no = no.prox` is executed. Since `no` is null, `no.prox` will cause NPE.
2. The loop exits when `no == null`, so the state of `no` before executing the second `if` statement is `null`, so `no.prox` causes NPE.